# Travelling to France 2 days before Visa Expiry

Tags: france, schengen-visas

My Schengen visa expires on 8 June and I am planning to travel to France on 6 June and stay for 2 weeks as my visa says 90 days stay. Is this possible or should I leave before expiry date?

Comment: I sure that you need to leave before expiry date.If you stay after that, you could be illegal.

Answer (score 4):

Your visa must be valid for the duration of your stay.  You may stay only until the expiration date, when you must leave by the end of the day.

This is explicit in the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412):

> The date of the last day of the period of the visa holder’s authorised stay is entered after the word ‘TO’ and is written in the same way as the first date. The visa holder must have left the territory for which the visa is valid by midnight on that date.